# What is the equivalent of Eclipse' Detail Formatter in Intellij ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a `Detail formatter` in Intellij similar to 'Edit Detail Formatter' in eclipse Debug? (This Eclipse feature is detailed [here](http://www.robertwloch.net/2012/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-detail-formatter/))

I have a org.w3c.dom.Document object referred in my projects. 
In the debug view I need to see the string value of the Document object. How can I achieve this in IntelliJ IDEA.

I tried to use 'Data Type Renderes', but not able to give the complete toString code in expressions.

Comment: It would be most useful to look at some sample code where we can try this out. Could you please extract a simple working java class to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have found the Intellij equivalent of Eclipse' detail formatter: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugger-data-type-renderers.html ;

As mentioned previously, it would be useful to look at some code.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called [Java Data Type Renderers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/java-data-type-renderers.html) in IntellliJ IDEA 2016.2:

> IntelliJ IDEA allows you to specify how different objects are displayed in the debugger on a class-by-class basis. You can assign the expressions to be displayed rather than rely on the object's String representation.
>   For example, if an object represents a user, you may want to see users represented by their login name; or, for a cache entry object, its age and contents may be appropriate. IntelliJ IDEA refers to these as type renderers.